# How to obtain GeoServer layer's shapefile name using REST API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I have a GeoServer store of type "Directory of Shape Files".  I have layers defined in that store corresponding to specific shapefiles. Some of my layers have been renamed.  I'm looking for how to pull from GeoServer the name of the shapefile a particular layer from this store is referencing.  Seems like it should be easy but I cannot find it anywhere...

Do I have to look in the XML files?

This is an old GeoServer running 2.8.2, I'm planning to move some layers to a newer version, and I want to make sure I get the right data files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This REST call will get the layers (called featuretypes in this API)

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/<workspace>/datastores/<store of shape files dir>/featuretypes.xml
```

Which returns a list of the layers published.  So for each you can then look at its details like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/<workspace>/datastores/<store of shape files dir>/featuretypes/<name of layer>.xml
```

Now look at the `<nativeName>` tag.  It has the name of the shapefile.